# Allow user to complete form with a delay, error : undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I try to allow user to fill the form with a delay between each user, 
The delay is set to 100 between the last user registered in my database and the new one

Here is what I do in my controller :

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def new
    @email = Email.new
  end

  def create
    if Time.now - Email.last.created_at < 100
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{render :new, notice: "Wait !"}
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        @email = Email.create(email_params)
        if@email.persisted?
          format.html {redirect_to invoice_index_path, notice: 'Email validated '}
        else
          format.html{render :new}
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

private

def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:email, :id_user)
  end
end

My view :

```
   <div class="container">
<% if flash[:notice].present?%>
    <center><p id="notice" class="alert alert-success"><%= flash[:notice] %></p></center>
<%end%>
<center><h1>Nouvelle Connection </h1></center>
    <%= form_with model: @email, local: true do |form|%>
        <% if @email.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error explanation" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Erreur(s) : </p>
                <ul>
                    <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
                        <li><%=message%></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :email %> :
            <%= form.email_field :email, placeholder: "Insérez votre email", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block", value: "Se connecter" %>
        </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

When I fill the form, nothing happen, just the url change from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://localhost:3000/emails` and when I re-click on Validate, it goes to `http://localhost:3000/emails/53` with the error `The action 'update' could not be found for EmailsController` but I guess I have this error because I don't have any update/edit in my controller.

Do you know how to fix that to allow me a delay between each user ?

Edit : I now have the error `undefined method errors for nil:NilClass` in my view at the line `<% if @email.errors.any? %>`. I understand this is because my @email is nil but I tried to integrate this in my view :

```
<% if @email.nil?%>
 <%= Wait for the moment %>
<%end%>
```

Also tried : `<% if @email&.errors&.any? %>` why so, I return to the URL : `http://localhost:3000/emails`
But still have the same error, do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in your view you check for `notice.present?` and that should be `flash[:notice].present?`. So then the error will be shown.

Secondly, in your controller you are actually *first* creating the email, and only then checking if it should be created, and then not even removing it? So the only result is that people will see a notice, but the email would still be created.

So instead do something like:

```
def create
  if Time.now - Email.last.created_at < 100
    respond_to do |format|
      @email = Email.new(email_params)
      format.html do
        flash[:notice] = 'Wait! You cannot enter emails so quickly!' 
        render :new
      end 
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      @email = Email.create(email_params)
      if @email.persisted?
        format.html {redirect_to invoice_index_path, notice: 'Email validé '}
      else
        format.html{render :new}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Secondly this does seem to mean that any user wanting to enter a new email, will be punished if another user has also entered another email. So in that case you might want to check as follows:

```
Email.where(created_by_id: current_user.id).last
```

to only check for `Email` 's the current user has entered (but maybe that is taking your problem/solution too far?).

Also note there are much better/efficient ways to throttle requests (rate limiting) using apache/nginx (which is probably how it will be deployed), so is this actually a good approach to handle in your ruby on rails code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I try to do it on a client side on mu localhost and indeed, I should check it with apache in a second time when we will deploy a second version ! Also edited my question because I have another error that I can't fix and don't get why

Comment: Ha, I edited my answer: when saving the email is not allowed, `@email` is not set, so "build" a new email with the given params and re-render the form, so the user can still edit or repost it. Also I saw in your view code you still try to print `notice`, should that not also be `flash[:notice]` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the modification I land on this URL: `http://localhost:3000/emails` and I don't have the errors messages. For the `flash[:notice] ` if edited my post, if you can confirm that I got you well on this.

Comment: Afaik you have to replace both occurences of `notice` by `flash[:notice]`, unless you have a helper called `notice` that translates to `flash[:notice]`? I generally iterate over all `flash` messages, and depending on the type I set the colour/class of the surrounding div. But if I understand correctly: everything is now working and you see the notice or not?

Comment: Hi ! I edited my view to let you know my change with the `flash[:notice]` in the `if` but I still don't see the notice. As I have only one message on this page, I can set it up like this, but thanks for the tips about setting the colour / class, I keep it in mind. So it works as expected but I just don't see the notice wait in my view

Comment: Right, I edited my answer. You can set the flash using `redirect_to path, notice: ...` but that does not work on `render` --> then it will only pass a local parameter. If you want both to work in the same way, you have to explicitly set the `flash[:notice]` before the render.